# How to resolve conflict of bootstrap datatable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to sort in descending order the registered companies by created On basis...
I added this line in controller

```
public ActionResult AllCompanyList(CompanyModel companyModel)
{
    companyModel.companyList = CompanyManager.GetAllCompanies().OrderByDescending(m=>m.CreatedOn).ToList();
}
```

and I added this on view

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered data-table", id="example">  
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function ()
     {
         $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "bootstrap", "aoColumns": null,    { "asSorting": ["desc"] },null ]});
     });
</script>
```

But every time companies are showing with descending order but data table is not working. What should I do?

Comment: So, where is the table? I see a start tag; the only allowable children at that point are `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>`, & `<tr>`. You also have a comma there that needs to go away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a plugin or another JavaScript file to include datatables with bootstrap. Check out [this link](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/bootstrap.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: <table class="table table-striped table-bordered data-table">
                <thead> <tr>  <th>Company Name  </th> </thead><tbody>@if (Model != null) { foreach (var item in Model.companyList){
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"> <label onclick="GetCompanyById(@item.Id)">@item.OrganisationName</label></a>(@item.Id)
                            </td></td>
                        </tr>
                    
                        }

                    }
                </tbody> </table>

Answer (score 0):

```
 tables need to be properly formatted, in-order for dataTables to work so put <thead> and <tbody> tag and remove "," from table tag
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, until when i removed **defer** in the line calling bootstrap.js file